# How to insert through bison actions OR return or pass an object to bison parser?

Tags: c++, bison

I have a GUI program which uses bison to do parsing of files (containing pin connection list of ICs). 
The input file is like->

```
3 = NAND2(1, 2)
6 = NAND2(4, 5)
8 = NAND2(9, 10)
11 = NAND2(12, 13)
```

And (simplified) grammar is like->

```
start : spec { cout << "Parse Complete!"; }
      ;

spec : '{' expr_list '}'
     ;

expr_list : expr_list expr | expr
          ;

expr : INT '=' FUNC '(' args ')' { /*WANT TO INSERT ACTION HERE */ }
     ;
```

At the place mentioned I want to perform an action -- to insert parsed values in my container (a `map`). The file generated by bison is `.cpp`, but really it is C otherwise. I can include required header files easily. Also I can simply call non-member functions (like `cout`).

My question is- How can I insert values in a object (of container type)? I can create an object inside grammar file, but then how do I return it?

Other way to do is to create an object (of container type) in GUI code, and then pass this to parser.

Please tell how to achieve any of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is `extern`.

I created the (global) object in **.cpp** file of my GUI (where I invoke the parser) like:

```
QStringList *icNameList;
```

Then in header file (included by bison file)

```
extern QStringList *icNameList;
```

Finally in bison file, I can do something like:

```
abc : xyz { icNameList->append(getTokenString()); }
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

With return value optimisation, I'd be tempted just to return a map by value.